# Can I run Kubernetes Control Plane (not Docker) on Android?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, microservices, kubernetes-pod

I want to run the Kubernetes Control Plane itself on an Android phone/device. Is this possible?

I'm not referring to running the containers on Android (which I understand is possible using Docker), but Kubernetes Control Pane (kube-controller-manager, etcd, kube-scheduler, kube-apiserver) which will control the containers. My goal is to run the entire cluster on an Android phone such that all components including the containers will run on a single or collection of phones.

Maybe the answer is obvious but I could not find anything in my research to suggest if this is possible or not especially because searching for "run kubernetes on Android" and its variants just end up taking me to search results for running Docker on android. Thank you.